# Show images on mypages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am now trying to show the images, which a user already registered, on his or her 'mypage'.
Then, I wrote some codes as below.But it doesn't work.Could you give me some advises?

☆members_controller

```
 @member= Member.find(params[:id])
 @member.groups.reverse.map do |group|
 @join_groups_images = group.imageurl
```

☆(members)show.html.erb

```
<div class="join_groups_images">
<%= image_tag @join_groups_images, :width => '20px' ,:height => '25px' %>
</div>
```

☆(model)member.rb

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :admin, :mail, :memo, :name, :pass, :user, :pass_confirmation

 has_many :group_in_members, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :groups, :through => :group_in_members
```

☆(model)group_in_member.rb

```
class GroupInMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :group_id, :member_id

  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :member
end
```

☆schema.rb

```
create_table "groups", :force => true do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.text     "memo"
   t.boolean  "admin"
   t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
   t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
   t.string   "imageurl"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide whole code from action in members controller, but I assume, that you are using .map{|| } in wrong way. You need a variable with array or even method in `Member` model.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def images
    groups.reverse.map(&:imageurl)
  end

  ...
end
```

and then, put this in your view

```
<ul class="join_groups_images">
  <% @member.images.each do |image| >
    <li><%= image_tag image %></li>
  <% end>
</div>
```

that should do the trick.